# How to deploy two projects into one Web app - Deploy using sub directory

Tags: azure, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I have two projects, JavaScript and Angular. I want to have both on the same web app on azure. 
The URL will be like:
**First Project**: www.wholeproject.com
**Second Project**: ww.wwholeproject.com/secondproject 
The projects are on the same git repository.

I created Azure web app and linked it to the first project, so deploying the first one is working and I can see it online. However, I can't manage to publish the second **(angular)** project having the subdirectory ../secondproject.

I tried adding the .deployment file to the main project, but I couldn't figure out how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this on your web app by using [virtual directories](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/).

The below two blogs highlight how to setup virtual directories with different URLs and how to deploy to each directory.

- http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2016/07/deploy-aspnet-core-10-web-application.html
- http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2017/06/deploying-web-apps-to-azure-virtual.html

Please let us know if you have any questions or concerns regarding this topic.